# Redirect to docs from landing page in docusaurus v2

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

Since I don't have a landing page, I would like to redirect to the main doc page docs/main

I tried to follow the instructions: https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-creation#docs-landing-page
from v1, but they don't seem to work for v2.
Can someone please give me detail instructions on how to accomplish this?

I have very limited experience with React.

Comment: Huh? I never voted on this question.

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to add the `baseUrl` via `useBaseUrl` just to be more robust.

Few ways of doing it:

### 1. `useEffect`

```js
import useBaseUrl from '@docusaurus/useBaseUrl';

function Home() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.location.href = useBaseUrl('/docs/main');
  }, []);
  return null;
}
```

### 2. `<Redirect/>`

Alternatively, use the `<Redirect>` component: https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core#redirect-

### 3. Create `index.html` page in `static` folder

And include the following code for redirects: https://v1.docusaurus.io/docs/en/site-creation#docs-landing-page

Comment: link to step 3 code is broken, couldn't find the right one to edit your response, sorry.

Comment: We recently moved some URLs so the subdomain has changed. Updated my answer

Comment: Why the useEffect? Without it it works for me but with it it throws some error that I need to use hooks inside the context of a component or sth like this

Answer (score 4):

Configure the `docId` of the `Docs` nav item to point to your main page

*File: docusaurus.config.js*

```json
{
  type: 'doc',
  docId: 'main',
  position: 'left',
  label: 'Docs',
}
```

Add the following `slug` to the top of your main page to have `/docs` redirect to it

*File: docs/main.mdx*

```
--- 
slug: /
---
```

Then create the following file to redirect `/docs/main` to `/docs`

*File: src/pages/docs/main.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect} from '@docusaurus/router';

export default function Home() {
  return <Redirect to="/docs" />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to docs only mode. You can refer to the official docs here:

https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-introduction#docs-only-mode

Change your docusaurus.config.js and add routeBasePath:'/' to docs object.

```
  module.exports = {
  // ...
  presets: [
    '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
    {
      docs: {
        routeBasePath: '/', // Serve the docs at the site's root
        /* other docs plugin options */
      },
      blog: false, // Optional: disable the blog plugin
      // ...
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32356072)